# testing system call in linux 2.6.39.4 kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am making a new system call for getting average waiting time of FCFS scheduling.
I named the system call name as "add2". Now after compiling the kernel successfully i am experiencing problem in testing the system call.

With some study I came up with these two programs for testing my system call. But still there is some problem in these. I think the problem is in passing arguments. Please help.

Here is the addnewsystemcall.h

```
#include<linux/unistd.h>
#define __NR_add2 307


long add2(int at[], int bt[], int n)
{
    return syscall(__NR_atvfcfs,i);
}
```

and here is the addnewsystemcall.c

```
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "add2.h"


int main()
{
    int avgwt;

    int n,i,at[50],bt[50];

    printf("\n\nEnter the number of processes:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n\n BURST TIME and ARRIVAL TIME of thr process");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n ARRIVAL TIME :");
        scanf("%d",&at[i]);
        printf(" BURST TIME : ");
        scanf("%d",&bt[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nAverage waiting time = ");
    printf("%d\n", add2(int at[], int bt[], int n)); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This code wont compile. Did you mean `add2(a, b, n)` in `printf` statement? In the implementation of `add2` where is `i` declared? You are not using any parameters passed

Answer (score 3):

Adding a system call is the hardest way to get information from a kernel. Don't do it, unless you really need to.

There are much better ways, such as:
1. Adding a virtual file under `/proc` or `/sys`. This gives you a textual interface, which is very easy to use.
2. Adding a device driver, creating a `/dev` file and using the `ioctl` function. This is harder to use, but may be more suitable for passing binary structures.

Comment: Or for hacking/debugging use debugfs.